# continuity of a function with singular integrand

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Define
$$
F(t)=\int_0^t(t-\tau)^{-0.5}f(\tau)d\tau~\mbox{for}~ t\in [0,0.5].
$$
I wonder if the function $F$ is continuous on $[0,0.5]$.

I would be grateful if you could give any comments on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite the convolution as
$$
F(t):=\int_0^t \tau^{-0.5}f(t-\tau)\,d\tau.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
F(t+h)-F(t)&=\int_0^{t+h} \tau^{-0.5}f(t+h-\tau)\,d\tau-\int_0^t \tau^{-0.5}f(t-\tau)\,d\tau \\
&=\int_0^t \tau^{-0.5}\left(f(t+h-\tau)-f(t-\tau)\right)\,d\tau\\
&+\int_t^{t+h}\tau^{-0.5}f(t+h-\tau)\,d\tau.
\end{align}
How can both integrals be made small?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know how to prove it. By the way, in your new form of $F$,  Isn't $f(\tau-t)$---> $f(t-\tau)$ ?

Comment: Just fixed it. Good call.